# how to display different input type based upon drop down values

Tags: javascript, html, mysql

I need to display input type date and datetime based upon dropdown values ., I need to do like if I select first value need to show only input type date and if I select second value need to show input type as datetime. I tried but I unable it is working..,

Thanks in advance

```js
function changeFunc() {
  v var chkmale = document.getElementById("male");
             var dvtext = document.getElementById("dvtext");
             dvtext.style.display = chkmale.checked ? "block" : "none";
     
             var chkfemale = document.getElementById("female");
             var dvtext1 = document.getElementById("dvtext1");
             dvtext1.style.display = chkfemale.checked ? "block" : "none";
}
```

```html
<!-- The Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal">
  <!-- Modal content -->
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <h2>Add detail</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
      <form>

        <label for="gender">Gender: </label>

        <select id="a" onchange="changeFunc();">
          <option> Select</option>
          <option id="male" name="gender" value="Male"> Male</option>
          <option id="female" name="gender" value="Female">FeMale </option>
        </select>

        <br>
        <br>
        <div id="dvtext" style="display: none">
          Enter your Height:
          <input type="date">
        </div>
        <div id="dvtext1" style="display: none">
          Enter your Weight:
          <input type="date">
        </div>
        <div class="alert-msg" style="text-align: center;"></div>
        <br>
        <input type="reset" />
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="col-lg-12">

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Place `id="Deadline" onclick="ShowHideDiv()"` on the `<select>`, not the `<option>`

Comment: I made you a snippet. Please do not post irrelevant server code if you are only interested in client code

Comment: @brombeer yes I did it but not working still., Shall i insert Javascript end of the page on php

Comment: `chkmale.selectedValue.checked` does not make any sense and = is assignment, you want `===` to test equality

Comment: if the dropdown value selected the date should show., that is what i need @mplungjan

Comment: I know what you want. See my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`chkmale.selectedValue.checked` does not make any sense and = is assignment, you want `===` to test equality

I suggest you use eventListener and simplify the script using proper variable and element names

The name of a select goes on the select too options do not have IDs or names

```js
document.getElementById("genderSelect").addEventListener("change",function() {
  const isMale = this.value === "Male"
  document.getElementById("dvtext").hidden = !isMale
  document.getElementById("dvtext1").hidden = !isMale
})
```

```html
<!-- The Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal">
  <!-- Modal content -->
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <h2>Add detail</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
      <form>

        <label for="gender">Gender: </label>

        <select id="genderSelect" name="gender">
          <option> Select</option>
          <option value="Male"> Male</option>
          <option value="Female">FeMale </option>
        </select>

        <br>
        <br>
        <div id="dvtext" hidden>
          Enter your Height:
          <input type="date" id="height" name="height">
        </div>
        <div id="dvtext1" hidden>
          Enter your Weight:
          <input type="date" id="weight" name="weight">
        </div>
        <div class="alert-msg" style="text-align: center;"></div>
        <br>
        <input type="reset" />
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="col-lg-12">

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Having only one question instead of getting value from local., how to get value from mysql database based on the value the input type need to change .,, do u have any idea about that., db connection code given below., it will be very helpful if i find the answer., Thank you.

Comment: <select name="selectCourseType" required>
        <option value=""  required>Select Courses Type</option>
         <?php
         
         $sql = mysqli_query($link,"SELECT * FROM courses_type ORDER BY ct_id DESC");
         $row = mysqli_num_rows($sql);
         while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)){
         echo "<option value='".$row['ct_id']."'>" . $row['ct_name'] ." </option>";
         }
         ?>
       </select>

Comment: I am not sure what you are asking Can you open a new question and if it is PHP related tag PHP and if JS related post HTML and JS - perhaps you are thinking of AJAX

Comment: Its related to php and mysql., My question is simple. need to display input type date and datatime based upon dropdown value retrieve from mysql database.,, code i commented above.,

Comment: It’s a new question

Comment: okay thank you is there any possible to help it on comment